# Renaming files does nothing Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, file-rename

I am working on renaming files in a directory. I run the code below with no errors, but the files stay the same name.

```
dir = 'H:\Projects\test'
files = glob.glob(dir)
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
for i, file in enumerate(files):
    try:    
       os.rename(file, '{dir}/attachment-{i}.txt')
       break
    except:
        print('rename failed')
```

The directory has multiple file types. So, I need them all rename regardless.
What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Is one file renamed? If so, `continue` instead of `break`. Or, just remove `break`

Comment: No files get renamed. Does it matter if I have the .txt at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what your call to `enumerate(...)` is actually returning.

Your `glob.glob(...)` line looks like it will only return the directory you are specifying, rather than its contents. If you wish to return the contents of your directory, instead of

```
dir = 'H:\Projects\test'
```

try

```
dir = 'H:\\Projects\\test\\*'
```

The double backslashes are necessary escape characters, and the asterisk at the end tells the glob command that you are interested in the contents of the directory, rather than the directory itself.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help!. How do I see what enumerate() is returning? I am getting a
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Just print its return values (in your example, i and file)

Comment: It is only returning one item in the folder instead of everything.